# How to fix '0 passed and exactly 1 expected' error in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm Created Form Request,it doesn't work. But if I put validation in the controller it is work.

i think it happend after (php artisan make:auth).
Because before that it was working properly.

```
//StorBlogPost : 

public function authorize()
{
    return true;

}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{

    $rules = [
        'name'          => 'bail|required',
        'camera'        => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'weight'        => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'price'         => 'bail|required|numeric',
        'barcode'       => 'bail|required',
        'production_at' => 'bail|required'
    ];
    return $rules;
}

 //controller :

public function store(StoreBlogPost $request)
    {
        $request->validate();
        product::create($request->except('_token'));
    }
```

error : 
"Too few arguments to function App\Http\Requests\StoreBlogPost::Illuminate\Foundation\Providers{closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected"

Comment: Isn't the error message saying which line has the error and in which file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to call `$request->validate()` in your controller. Laravel calls this automatically.